# How to uninstall AWS client in windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, client

I am using windows AWS client to connect to the AWS VM service. Client ask me for update each time I run it, but when I'm trying to update AWS client it says "Removing application: Please wait while the Setup wizard installs Amazon Workspaces" [image] but then it says to locate the package, if I provide the path of the package I just ran it shows me the new error: [image]

After cancelling the installation, it says:[image]

I tried to remove this client, but the same error appeared: provide installation package. I deleted all folders, removed installation record and cleared the registry, but still having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to uninstall the older version. Using 3rd party registry tool, I searched and removed every registry key contains "Amazon". After reboot, the client installed successfully.
This was fine with me, because I use only this software from Amazon and this is my local PC.
Don't try this at home if you are not sure what you do.